# In Python why is calling super() function for a class with no superclass defined is not an error?

Tags: python

For a Python novice, please can someone tell me what is happening here? Why is it printing "A init"?

If i remove the line `super().__init__()` from `__init__` function of class `B` then the behaviour is as expected. But why is below code not an error, I though `B` would not have a superclass??

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print("A init")

class B:

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   # why is this line not an error
        print("B init")

class C(B, A):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("C init")

c = C()
```

### Output

```
A init

B init

C init

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: in python 3 all classes inherit from `object`.

Comment: I see. But when i call the constructor of C then why is it printing "A init", I was thinking as per MRO rules it would only print "B init" as it resolved to the "left most class"? It seems the init function of B is calling the init function of A.

Comment: i think C is calling both A and B, multiple inheritance

Comment: Hmm. As per my understanding, C should call its own init function, if defined., and in my code when I call init of super() in init of C then it should call init of B as B is the "superclass" by precedence (left-most) as it C is defined as C(B,A)

Comment: You're not wrong on either point. C does call its own, and B calls A in this case. `b = B()` will *not* call A. gilch's answer seems to give the reasoning per MRO. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I understand now.

Comment: BTW you can use this online tool to visualize code execution http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 4):

You create an instance of `C`, which we'll call `self`. It has an MRO of `C`, `B`, `A`, `object`.

`C`'s `__init__` first calls `super().__init__()`. This delegates to the `__init__` in the next class in the MRO, which is B, *using the same `self` object*.

`B`'s `__init__` first calls `super().__init__()`. This delegates to the `__init__` in the next class in the MRO of `self`'s class (`C`), which is `A`.

`A`'s `__init__` prints and returns to `B`'s `__init__`.

`B`'s `__init__` prints and returns to `C`'s `__init__`.

`C`'s `__init__` prints and returns to the constructor (`object`'s `__new__`), which returns `self`.

`super()` has two hidden arguments, `__class__` (so it knows where to start from in the MRO), and `self` (or `cls`, for `@classmethod`s—it's whatever the first argument is, regardless of name).

You had to provide these explicitly in Python 2 (and still can), but in Python 3 `super()` actually inspects the stack frame of its caller and finds these when called from inside a method. (The `__class__` variable is implicitly available inside methods, and is the class it was defined in.)